# Не работает dom манипуляция

Tags: javascript

Пытался поменять фон в браузере, у меня выходит следующая ошибка:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')
at scripts.js:1**

Здесь почему-то все работает, а у меня нет.
В чем проблема?

У меня код такой же как и в этом примере.

```js
document.body.style.background = 'red'; // сам скрипт находится в отдельном js файле
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

   <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link  href="style.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>
  </head>

 <body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Я бы делал так: красил бы body в красный цвет путем добавления класса. Те стили через css, а через js добавить body какой-то класс. Думаю в вашем случае не может быть прочитано свойство несуществующего объекта. Я бы через console.log вывел сначала document, потом document.body и т.д., по идее при выводе в консоль там будет видно объект и его свойства

Comment: А, кстати, может быть у вас js скрипт запускается до того, как завершена загрузка и построение DOM документа. В моем последнем вопросе есть пример реализации запуска js скрипта после того, как завершена загрузка и построение DOM документа

Comment: @freestyle_HD не могу найти ваш вопрос с примером, если вам не трудно, то не могли бы вы пожалуйста дать ссылку. Буду очень признателен))

Comment: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1327662/] Там кусок кода начинается с: ```document.addEventListener```. Вот это кусок кода вам и нужен. Пишите внутри функции ```function pageLoadedHandler() { ``` ваш код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скрипты надо в конец `body` ложить или использовать `defer` если скрипт юзает DOM

1.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

   <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link  href="style.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

 <body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

2. 

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

   <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link  href="style.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script defer type="text/javascript" src="java.js"></script>
  </head>

 <body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: А что такое defer?

Comment: `defer` - значит отложи загрузку и исполнение скрипта пока `DOM` не будет готов