# Помогите понять, зачем нужен callback, если можно вроде обойтись и без него

Tags: javascript

Колбэки в js так или иначе перекликаются со слушателями событий.
Пример моей реализации слушателя:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", pageLoadedHandler);

function pageLoadedHandler() {
  console.log('завершена загрузка и построение DOM документа');
}
```

В этом примере мне понятно что только по достижению события: DOMContentLoaded, вызовется функция pageLoadedHandler

Но есть другой пример с функцией колбэком:
Существует 2 функции: func1, func2

func1 должна быть вызвана только по достижению события из функции func2

func1 в данном случае является функцией обратного вызова или колбэком.

Используя иструмент языка: колбэки, нужно func1 передать как аргумент функции 2.

```js
let some_var = "dobrih vecherov";

function func1(a) {
  //do something with a
}

function func2(my_callback, b) {
  //some code here

  //ajax request must return response,
  //but you need to wait a bit until a response from the server arrives

  //some condition for callback function
  if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
    my_callback(b);
  }
  
}

func2(func1, some_var);
```

Если колбэк вешается на событие, то с таким же успехом я могу запустить функцию func1 по событию:

```js
function func1(a) {
  //do something with a
}

function func2(b) {
  //some code here

  //ajax request must return response,
  //but you need to wait a bit until a response from the server arrives

  //some condition for func1
  if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
    func1(b);
  }

}

func2(some_var);
```

Результат выполнения обоих сценариев на вид одинаков: func1 вызвана только по достижению события из функции func2

Вопрос: зачем тогда колбэки нужны, если я и так могу функцию по событию запустить? Можете привести пример, где четко понятно в сравнении как в моем примере, почему нужно использовать именно callback.

Comment: Вызывая `func1` внутри `func2`, Вы тем самым лишаете возможности вызвать какой-нибудь `func3` вместо `func1`, если в этом возникла бы необходимость. `function func3(a) {
  //do something other with a
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пример вы уже сами привели в самом начале. Почему метод `addEventListener` не может запустить функцию `pageLoadedHandler` без явной передачи её в аргументе? Потому что он универсальный, и не знает о ней. И не знает, что именно её нужно запускать, а не сотни других.

Так же и в собственном методе может быть подобная ситуация. Напишите сами аналог метода `addEventListener`. Сразу станет понятно, что внутри него вы не знаете какую именно функцию вызывать, но знаете, что нужно что-то вызвать. Поэтому требуется аргумент-колбэк. Или какой-то другой способ доставки какой-то функции внутрь другой функции.

Если вы можете вызвать функцию сразу, и всякая универсальность не требуется, то и колбэк не нужен.